# Buddy build error Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

Tags: ios, xcode8, carthage

I am using carthage in project. I am able to successfully generate ipa from Xcode. But while building from buddy build, getting error "Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0". Somebody can help?

Comment: Using Xcode 8 and carthage 0.18

Comment: Try Automatic signing in

Comment: I tried it but no luck. Do you have idea of carthage? I think carthage is adding framework to embedded binary and that's causing code signing error, not sure.

Comment: I too faced this issue for my App which have iMessage extension, You have extensions in your App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed now. Need to disable archive option in App settings.